# SPI's CPHA description in NXP's Block Guide

Tags: spi

:)

I'm a little confused about the CPHA description on the **SPI Block Guide V04.01** from Motorola/NXP.
The description is the following:

> "If the CPHA bit in SPI Control Register 1 is clear, odd numbered
> edges on the SCK input cause the data at the serial data input pin to
> be latched. Even numbered edges cause the value previously latched
> from the serial data input pin to shift into the LSB or MSB of the SPI
> shift register, depending on the LSBFE bit. If the CPHA bit is set,
> even numbered edges on the SCK input cause the data at the serial data
> input pin to be latched. Odd numbered edges cause the value previously
> latched from the serial data input pin to shift into the LSB or MSB of
> the SPI shift register, depending on the LSBFE bit."

My confusion is about **why using different clock edges (I mean rising vs. falling or vice-versa) to latch the serial data input and to shift it into the shift register?
What does motivate this behavior?** Doesn't it make a configurable master device much more complicated? Doesn't it make STA more complicated as well?
I did some sketches here and it seems to be possible to use the same clock edge to latch the serial input data and to shift it into the shift-register without any penalty...

[SPI waves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ6sy.png)

[SPI MASTER SLAVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8vq6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your sketch does not consider delay skews, and setup and hold parameters of triggers.
Different edges had been chosen a long time ago to guarantee that imperfections listed above do not affect interface operation.

Consider an internal SPI core clock that shifts data. This clock and data are routed to IC pins using buffers which transistors have much more working current than internal ones. So they are much larger and *slower*. If you use the same edge, delay deviation can lead to the situation when data comes to the output pin even earlier than the clock. Moreover, you should guarantee that delay of output buffer for data is longer than the delay of the clock buffer plus *any* possible data hold time of input trigger in SPI slave. Thus the slowest possible slave will limit SPI clock frequency *at master design phase*.
With different edges you can just set SCK frequency low enough to meet slow slaves data setup/hold requirements and set the frequency high for fast slaves.

p.s. All configuration in master hardware is done using a couple of XOR gates (plus config bits themselves).

Comment: So does this picture describes better than most an SPI master-slave pair? https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8vq6.png - I mean, most pictures doesn't show the sample register with the inverted clock edge.

Comment: Another question: should I assume the maximum path delay between master and slave is ~0.5 SCK cycle for the system to work properly?

Comment: Regarding the picture -- it's more correct. To be precise, it's correct if we assume Clock generator output is high on idle. In this case the picture shows right registers placement/active edges for CPHA=0 (shift reg output goes to the pin immediately) and CPOL=1 (sample on falling edge, shift on rising edge).

Comment: Regarding "0.5 SCK cycle" -- it's a very good question. Maximum _loop_ delay should be <0.5T. Loop delay is a sum of delay from the master SCK output to slave SCK input (may include level shifter, long wires) _plus_ slave clock-to-output delay _plus_ slave MISO to master MISO delay (also -- level shifter, long wires) _plus_ master setup time.